# This question is primarily opinion-based, but it's a reasonable one. Should we leave it open?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How common is it that salaries are made public?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/40131/437)

This question is primarily opinion-based, but someone can develop [a very reasonable answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/40134/437).

Should we leave it open?

Comment: If you work for public sector, then salaries are public

Comment: The question you cited should be closed. The OP can do his own research.

Comment: It is not opinion based at all but it is overly broad.  The answer varies by industry and location.

Comment: @Sonihal: Sometimes but not always.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would disagree that it's an opinion-based question.  While a good source for the data is hard to come by, the question itself is very objective.

The three answers it has received so far seem pretty on-point.  Chris Lively's answer is certainly subjective, but not opinion-based.

RualStorge's 4th section should probably be removed, as it wanders away from the question.  However, I'd leave that to him as a comment for him to consider.

I would side with leaving it open, and pruning any answers that appear that focus on the merits of open wage structures, rather than answer the question about their occurrence rates.